# What verb form should come after "ALREADY", "Present" or "Past Participle"?

Tags: grammar, tense

What is the correct verb form to use with the word "already"? Should I use the present form of the verb or past participle form of the verb?
Example:

1. Already share your video in my Facebook.
2. Already shared your video in my Facebook.

Which one is correct?

Comment: What is the complete sentence, including the subject?  You wrote past participle rather than past tense―do you mean that you're omitting *have* as well as the subject?  That seems unlikely to me.

Comment: You mean, I should say, "I have already shared your..."
Can I use it omitting "subject" & "auxiliary verb"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "Already shared your video in my Facebook profile" to mean "I have already shared your video on my Facebook profile" or even "Already shared it." if the meaning would be clear in context. This kind of terse *I'm-busy-gotta-run* writing often employs ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

The adverb already means before now or before a particular time in the past. So it is usually used in the present perfect and the past perfect. However, we can also use it in the past simple in American English. As far as the present simple is concerned, we can use it only when we want to emphasize a situation or we express our surprise that something has happened so early such as  I am late already. It's five o'clock already?

Already share your video in my Facebook is OK if you are emphasizing this situation. Normally, we should say "Already have shared your video in my facebook. Already shared your video in my facebook is OK and acceptable in American English, not in British English. Moreover, it'll be appropriate if you write your sentences in full with the subject such as I have already shared your video in my facebook, etc.