# The question about "Had done" and "did"

Tags: grammar, tense

> As he ___ his report last Friday, Andrew is able to help his
>   colleagues this week.
>
> (A)        already submitted
>
> (B)        had already submitted

The correct answer is `already submitted` to put into the blank, the explanation says because of `giving exactly the time point(last Friday)`.

But I think `had already submitted` is better because the phrase more emphasizes the action of submitting completely done, therefore making Andrew helping others become possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the use of the word **already** that is pertinent in this question.

The choice between **past simple** and **past perfect** is often optional but not always.

Omitting **already** it would be more natural to write:

> As he submitted his report last Friday, Andrew.....

But **already** generally requires the present perfect or past perfect.

> I have already done the work

and NOT: *I already did the work*

Or

> I had already completed the work before she arrived.

The same applies in your example.

So you are correct to conclude that the sentence should read:

> As he had already submitted his report....

Comment: Thanks, this question and explanation are from a Japanese exercise book, and I also asked my Chinese friends about it, base on the Chinese high school lesson, the trick is if seeing time point, pick the _past simple_ as the answer in the exam...

Comment: @Jiu The guidance you refer to is simply wrong; See the previous Stack Exchange answer on this point: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/what-verb-form-should-come-after-already-present-or-past-participle

Comment: Got it, feel pathetic about Chinese&Japanese English education.